# Changing the background Image on a UIButton programmatically

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Within my application I am setting up some actions to allow users to create/edit/delete some options via webservices.  While allowing to do this, I needed to implement a timer to stop the people from just repeatedly add, delete, add, delete..... When the user presses the button, I call a method like so [sender setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal].  This appears to work just fine.

When my timer is invalidated after x seconds I am calling another method to restore the background image [changeAdminPinBtn setBackgroundImage:image forState:UI....].  image points to @"button.png" btw.

This above method is not changing my background image back.  A property has been declared for the UIButton but cannot seem to find the way of changing the buttons backgroundImage to the image that I want.

The initial UI is wired up in IB and I'm trying to change the properties of these buttons programmatically.

Can someone help shed some light on the issue please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of few things to check:

1. Function really got called.
2. `changeAdminPinBtn` set up and linked to IB correctly.
3. No other `setBackgroundImage` anywhere else.

Comment: the method is being called.  I have some logging to console, appears that the button is wired correctly in IB and there are no other set messages defined elsewhere (other than changing initially when button gets pressed).

Comment: looks like I did in fact forget to connect an Outlet to this button.  Much appreciated!